# Dropdownlist changes all values in Gridview when selected and not specific row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu, foreach

I have a DropDownList in a Gridview that allows you to start or stop services on remote servers. The DropDownList will allow you to start or stop services but it starts right from the first service in the list and loops through all of them. How can I get the DropDownList to only perform action on the service name for that specific row and not the entire Gridview? The services are added to a list that is binded to the GridView. Thanks.

```
    protected void ddlAction_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
    options.Username = "myUsername";
    options.Password = "myPassword"; 
    options.EnablePrivileges = true;
    serverName.Text = "myServerName";

    if (txtbox2.Text != string.Empty)
    {
        //Create the scope that will connect to the default root for WMI
        var scope = new ManagementScope(string.Format(@"\\{0}\root\cimv2", serverName.Text), options);
        scope.Connect();

        //Create a path to the services with the default options
        ObjectGetOptions option = new ObjectGetOptions(null, TimeSpan.MaxValue, true);
        ManagementPath spoolerPath = new ManagementPath("Win32_Service");
        ManagementClass servicesManager = new ManagementClass(scope, spoolerPath, option);
        try
        {
            //Get all of the services running on this server
            using (ManagementObjectCollection services = servicesManager.GetInstances())
            {
                foreach (ManagementObject service in services)
                {
                    list.Add(new myServers() { Name = service["Name"].ToString(), State = service["State"].ToString(), Servers1 = serverName.Text });

                    GridViewRow gvr = ((DropDownList)sender).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;

                    if (gvr != null)
                    {
                        //We can find all the controls in this row and do operations on them
                        var ddlQuantity = gvr.FindControl("ddlAction") as DropDownList;
                        if (ddlQuantity != null)
                        {
                            if (ddlQuantity.SelectedValue != "-1")
                            {
                                if (ddlQuantity.SelectedValue == "1")
                                {
                                    service.InvokeMethod("StartService", null);
                                }
                                else if (ddlQuantity.SelectedValue == "2")
                                {
                                    service.InvokeMethod("StopService", null);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)

        {
            throw;
        }
        gvServer.DataSource = list;

        gvServer.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are invoking your method in a `foreach` loop. You need to know which one dropdown index changed (like some `i`) and then invoke your method for `services[i]` only

Comment: Thanks Mark. Can you please provide an example code?

Comment: It is hard to know what you need your foreach loop for and other methods and what your view is. But hope the answer is useful. Use `CurrentCell.RowIndex` to get index of current selected row

Comment: I will need the foreach because later I would need to single out certian services. Such as the .Contains or .Endswith. As of right now I'm only trying to get the dropdown to function as expected.

Answer (score 0):

There is the `SelectedIndex` property for the `GridView`:

```
int i = yourGridView.SelectedIndex;
```

Then in your code remove **foreach** if you don't need it, and change your invoking lines to perform actions on `i` element:

```
services[i].InvokeMethod("StartService", null);
```

And to stop the service:

```
services[i].InvokeMethod("StopService", null);
```

Comment: Thanks Mark for providing me with an example and explaining. I will need to keep the foreach. Also GridView doesn't have a CurrentCell property. Would I need to change my GridView to DataGridView?

Comment: Thanks. I will give that a try. I really appreciate it!